# MongoDB, aggregation query an Multipoint geoindexes

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, geospatial

I am trying to query a 2dsphere geo-index which has Multipoints in its coordinates. According to the mongodb documentation, it's a new feature from 2.6, and I did not find a good example for querying it.

My code works fine with a coordinate of Type Point, but not when I change it to MultiPoint.

I am using mongoose and nodejs.

This is the mongoose schema :

```
AnnonceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    [...]
    geo: {type: Object, index: '2dsphere',name:String }
});
```

My search method :

```
AnnonceSchema.statics.search = function(long, lat, maxDistanceInKm, done){
    var Annonce = this;
        Annonce.aggregate(
            [
                { $match: [...]
                { $match: { "geo": {$within: {$centerSphere: [
                    [long, lat],
                        maxDistanceInKm / 6371
                 ]}}}},
                { $sort: { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } },
                { $project: { title: 1, _id: 1, score: { $meta: "textScore" }}},
                { $match: { score: { $gt: 1.0 } } }
            ], done);
};
```

My unit test:

```
var notReturned = {[...], geo: 
    {type: 'MultiPoint', coordinates:[[2.65, 48.79]]}};

var returned = {[...], geo: {type: 'Point', coordinates:[2.65, 48.79]}};
Model.create(doesNotWork, function(){
    Model.create(doesWork, function(){
        Annonce.searchAnnonce(2.65, 48.79, 30, function (err, annonces) {
        assert.strictEqual(annonces.length, 2);
 });
});
```

I don't know what I am missing, the coordinates are good, the 2 objects are the sames, the only thing that is different is their their type and that I put an array of arrays for MultiPoint.

Did anyone already tried this feature ? How to query MultiPoints geo indexes ?

Thank you

Comment: I have found a mongodb JIRA ticket which may be related to my problem, put it's for geoNear and not geoWithin, so I wonder if it's related : https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11004?jql=text%20~%20%22MultiPoint%22

Comment: What happens if you put a second point in -- even conceivably repeating the first. That bug, which may well be related, relates to the fact that you have two sets of square brackets, ie, it is a multipoint, but only one point.

Comment: This cannot work. You are trying to use a "geo" query in the second `$match` stage of the aggregation pipeline. That is just not possible as the only place such a query can be run is in the "first" pipeline stage where an index can actually be selected, which is required for a "geo" query. It also appears that your first pipeline match is a text search, and these types of indexes cannot be mixed in the one query.

Comment: @JohnBarça In fact, I tried first with two points in my multipoint and it did not work, so I tried to simplify my problem and put only one point. The result is the same.

Comment: @NeilLunn Actually, we should be able to do a match with geoWithin anywhere we want, it's geoNear matches that we have to put on the first pipeline. As I said, my request works well with a Point, I can mix geoWithin and Text search without any problems.

Comment: @ktulu77 You misunderstand this. Any geo query must use an index. An index is only used in the first pipeline stage. Never after.

Comment: @NeilLunn I'm not sure. In the mongodb documentation, we can read :     When using $geoNear, consider that: You can only use $geoNear as the first stage of a pipeline.
Also, we can read for $match : Restrictions :To use $text in the $match stage, the $match stage has to be the first stage of the pipeline.

But there is nothing about geoWithin, and that's why I changed my code to use it instead of geoNear. Again, as I said, my aggregation works very well with points.

Comment: @ktulu77 This is not about $geoNear but all about the **first** pipeline stage. The aggregation pipeline **alters** the structure of the documents in the collection by definition. Even if you do not do that, only the **first** stage has access to using an index. Everything else following cannot use an index which is what you would be asking from a geoSpatial query of any type, or even a text search after the first stage. Believe me. I have poked around and contributed on code to know this is a fact.

Comment: @NeilLunn I retried my unit tests to be sure, but it does work well with full text search + geoWithin in aggregations. I have just upgraded Mongodb to the last version (2.6.5), and I cannot reproduce my problem anymore, my unit tests are Ok with MultiPoints or Points.

Comment: @NeilLunn I have also this in the documentation which can explain why it works with geoWithin : Both 2d and 2dsphere indexes can support inclusion queries. MongoDB does not require an index for inclusion queries after 2.2.3; however, these indexes will improve query performance.